# How to convert this stored procedure to retain or delete data from past 7 days

Tags: mysql, heidisql

Where
IFNULL(d.updated,d.inserted) < (CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), "*",MONTH(NOW)), "*", "01") -INTERVAL ',date_logs,' DAY):"):

Question : I need to create a stored procedure that cab delete data from past 7 days the above codes is for 30 days only .please help im just new to sql thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret is in the usage of `NOW()` (converted to `date` to remove the current time of the day) and removing 7 days with `interval '7 DAY'`

the where condition should be similar to

```
Where IFNULL(d.updated,d.inserted) < NOW()::date - interval '7 DAY';
```

Comment: `NOW()::date - interval '7 DAY'` can be simplified to `current_date - 7`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but im getting an error when i tried to call it can you recheck my query  IFNULL(d.updated,d.inserted) <CURRENT_DATE -7)  -INTERVAL ',date_logs,' DAY);");

Comment: And this is how I call the procedure     CALL procedure_name('db_name',7)

Comment: Im getting the error : right syntax to use near ')-INTERVAL 7 DAY)'

Comment: Postgres does not have an `IFNULL` function/statement. What you want is *coalesce(<list>)* to choose the first non-null value from list. So: `coalesce(d.updated,d.inserted) < current_date -7`

Comment: I just corrected the tagging it's mysql apologies.